# Layout broken across all sites on network even when theme changed

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

we have a multisite network with five subsites and the layout is broken across each of them on our development environment. This even appears to be the case when the theme is changed to the default WordPress twentyseventeen theme, and we have also tried deactivating/activating plugins.

For example on one of the subsites, the layout is displaying like this this: [image]

However it should look like this:

[image]

We are seeing a similar issue with the WP Admin interface, again affecting only our development multisite network (not our UAT/production environments).

We are also seeing minor layour issues with options pages in wp-admin:

[image]

Although it should look like this:

[image]

Changing the theme does not resolve this either.

I can confirm the following has been attempted with no resolution:

1. Changing to default 'twentyseventeen' theme
2. Deactivating all plugins
3. Reactivating the plugins 1-by-1
4. Checking the theme licensing is up to date
5. Ensured custom CSS in our development environment matches that in our production environment

Are there any issues that are known to cause this and any known fixes that we may have missed?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you checked if you have some 404 error on the loading of the css files? There might be somewhere a hardcoded url that is giving 404 and thus breaks the site.

Comment: Hi @ale, thanks for the response. I have checked and the css files are not returning 404 errors. Is there anything else that could be causing this? As mentioned, our live environment is not having this issue although it our development environment we are having this problem.

Comment: One other thing i can think of is the possibility for the local environment to have a different loading sequence for the css files. This can make some other css to be loaded later and to overwrite previous styles. of course this just a guess but you can check the styles in the local environment and if all of them are applied just as on the live. Also check if there are some changes in the html structure. Download the html source and do a file comparison between the two states (live and local) for easier check of the structure.

Comment: This seems strange. Can you compare the `wp-config.php` files of the 2 environments? 
If you see `define( ‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, true );` try changing that to `define( ‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false );`.